# Does ActiveRecord overwrite changes from objects loaded at different times?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord in Ruby **WITHOUT** Rails. If I use the following code, will the change to the attribute on first overwrite the change made to the attribute on second. Both first and second are the same record.

```
def my_method
  first = MyClass.find(1)
  first.my_attribute = "I am an attribute"
  first.save
end

second = MyClass.find(1)
second.my_attribute = "this is my attribute"
my_method
second.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Record has no identity map: although `first` and `second` represent the same row in the database, the two in memory objects are separate and are unaware of each other

The save in `my_method` will complete and then the second save will overwrite those changes.

If you want to be able to detect this sort of thing, one approach is [optimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html). This allows you to detect when a stale object is saved: the second save would raise an exception. You can activate this in your class by adding an integer column called `lock_version` (Make sure it has a default of 0)